# Using quicksight boto3 update_data_source

Tags: python, boto3

**Summary**

What is the right syntax to use [update_data_source](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.update_data_source) Quicksight boto3 to change credentials ?

**Context**

I am trying to use update data source method for Quicksight on boto3 to update my Redshift credentials in Quicksight.

My issue is that it is passing a dictionary as key to another dictionary. How can I unpack that to get to the username / password for Redshift ?

**Code**

My code looks like this :

```py
def main():
    qs = boto3.client('quicksight', region_name=region_name)

    response = qs.update_data_source(
            AwsAccountId='awsaccountid',
            DataSourceId='datasourceid',
            Name='qs_test',
            Credentials={
                {
                    'CredentialPair':{
                    'Username': 'test_user'
                    'Password': 'my_pass'
                    }
                }
                }
            )


    print(response)

main()
```

Also tried the below

```py
response = qs.update_data_source(
            AwsAccountId='awsaccountid',
            DataSourceId='datasourceid',
            Name='qs_test',
            Credentials={CredentialPair
                {
                RedshiftParameters=[
                    {
                    'Database': 'dbname',
                    'ClusterId': 'clusterid'
                    }
                }
                ],
            Credentials={
                'CredentialPair': {
                    'Username': 'test_user',
                    'Password': 'my_pass'
                    }
                }
            )


print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below syntax works :

```py
def main():
    qs = boto3.client('quicksight', region_name=region_name)

    response = qs.update_data_source(
            AwsAccountId='awsaccountid',
            DataSourceId='datasourceid',
            Name='qs_test',
            DataSourceParameters={
                'RedshiftParameters'={
                    'Database': 'dbname',
                    'ClusterId': 'clusterid'
                    }
                }
            }
            Credentials={
                'CredentialPair':{
                    'Username': 'test_user'
                    'Password': 'my_pass'
                }
            }
    )
    print(response)

main()
```

Comment: can you help me to create RDS dataset for quicksight using boto3?